# How to get only necessary html code by .ajax post method

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../includes/load_second",
    data: {
        ID: ID
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
        $('.new-nav1').html(msg);
    }
});
```

How can I get only html code of div in `load_second.php`, for example `id="table"`?

Comment: What is the result of `msg`?

Comment: `var $new = $(msg).appendTo($('.new-nav1').empty());
        //now use $new and find to find the elements you are targetting like $new.find('.myclass')`

Comment: the whole html code of load_second.php

Comment: he still loads full html code. I wrote $new.find('#table') after this code, is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to load a portion of a page into a element

```
$('.new-nav1').load("../includes/load_second #table", {ID:ID});
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Is it supported on many browsers? People recommended to use ajax

Comment: @user3434212 this is ajax just simplified, it has exactly the same support as `$.ajax`